# Getting "google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Request contains an invalid argument" error , in list_projects method in ProjectsClient class

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-resource-manager

I am trying to list out projects using resourcemanager api.
I am using the below code.

```
from google.cloud import resourcemanager
from google.cloud.resourcemanager import ProjectsClient
from google.oauth2 import service_account
path_json_file = "C:\\Users\\######\\Downloads\\dev-####-analyt-datal-svc- db.json"
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(path_json_file)
client =resourcemanager.ProjectsClient(credentials=credentials)
print(client)
request = resourcemanager.ListProjectsRequest(
   parent="###-amea-fldr/###-amea-analytics-fldr/##-amea-analytics-dev-fldr",
)
page_result = client.list_projects(request=request)
print(page_result)
```

I am using service account authentication. It has resourcemanager.projects.list permission also.

But I am getting the below error.

```
raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
details = "Request contains an invalid argument."
debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1658894641.118000000","description":"Error received 
from peer ipv6:[2404:6800:4007:809::200a]:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":967,"grpc_message":"Request contains an invalid argument.","grpc_status":3}"
```

Is this due to any error in the value passed to the argument "parent"?

Whether the way I have called the list_projects method is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think so.

See the definition of `parent` in [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) for [Cloud Resource Manager](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/) v3 [`projects.list`](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects/list) where you can try the API method (for your parameters) in the browser.

The `parent` resource can be tricky but, the example cited on this page is `folder/{folder}`.

I don't know because I don't have access to an org but you may be able to repeat the path i.e. `/folder/{parent-folder}/folder/{child-folder}`.

Try permutations in the APIs Explorer.

If it works there, it'll work using the (any) client library.

Comment: folder/{project id of parent} worked. Thank you

Comment: I'm pleased to hear it!